# Material UI TextField label does not move up when the value for TextField is set porgramatically

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I have a `TextField` element that is connected to `react-hook-form`. When I focus on that input I open a list of countries, so that I can choose a country to populate its phone code into the field through `setValue` function from `react-hook-form`.

Everything works okay, the country code does appear in the field but the label that normally moves up when you enter a text manually does not move up.

Here is what it looks like
[image]

Comment: Could you share your code? Just relevant part?

Comment: Have a look at this. https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#shrink

Comment: `shrink` is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: It should do automatically.

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this

```
InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
```

to your TextField properties.

Comment: In this case, you will not get the desired result. For ordinary TextField if it's empty and you are blurring the field, the label will not get shrink, and you need to add additional check for that which is not correct.

Comment: This will alter the original shrink behavior of the label, which is not intended.

Answer (score 15):

I also had same issue when i was updating textfield value programmatically in my reactjs project, what worked for me is using javascript ternary operator as shown in code below:

```
const [name,setName]=useState('')

somefunction = () => setName('abc')

        <TextField
          required
          variant="outlined"
          label="...some label..."
          // value={name} instead of this line write below line
          **value={name ? name : ''}**
          onchange={...somefunction...}
        />
```

Comment: Can you explain why this code works? Thanks.

Comment: When the initial value is `null`, the label will not get shrinked when updated. (See https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/13013).

Comment: This should be the correct answer (or, a simplified version: value ?? ''), when the initial value is undefined, react sees it as uncontrolled and then it switches to controlled (which is unsupported), by always populating value it lets react know this is a controlled component which then works properly.

Comment: That fits to my case

Answer (score 1):

Just add `defaultValues` to `useForm()` as empty string just as Ernesto said

```
  const {control, formState, handleSubmit, setError, setValue} = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      name: ''
    }
  });
```

and use `<Controller/>` as described [here](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller)

```
<Controller
        name="name"
        control={control}
        render={({field})=>(
        <TextField
          {...field}
          label="The label"
          variant="standard"
          fullWidth
        />
      )} />
```

Comment: Thanks man, the label was sticked because initially it wants empty string

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the variable that is referenced in the `value` cannot be `null`.

This line will mess up the `textField`:

```
const [person, setPerson] = useState()
```

This line will work:

```
const [person,setPerson] = useState({name:''})

< TextField label="Name" value={person.name} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I use it like this in react form hook, when any value comes in, the label part automatically goes up.

```js
import {Control, Controller, FieldValues} from "react-hook-form";
import {TextField} from "@mui/material";
import type {HTMLInputTypeAttribute} from "react";

export type TInputText = {
  name: string,
  control: Control<FieldValues, any>,
  label?: string,
  placeholder?: string,
  onChange?,
  type?: HTMLInputTypeAttribute
}

export default function InputText(props: TInputText) {
  let id = 'input-text-' + props.name;

  return (
    <Controller
      name={props.name}
      control={props.control}
      render={({field: {onChange, value}}) => (
        <TextField
          id={id}
          type={props?.type}
          onChange={(e) => {
            onChange(e)
            if (props.onChange) props.onChange(e);
          }}
          InputLabelProps={{ shrink: value?.length > 0 }}
          value={value}
          label={props?.label}
          placeholder={props?.placeholder}
        />
      )}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation documented on materialui site:

"*The input label "shrink" state isn't always correct. The input label is supposed to shrink as soon as the input is displaying something. In some circumstances, we can't determine the "shrink" state (number input, datetime input, Stripe input). You might notice an overlap.*"

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#limitations

To overcome this issue I've created a new variable to store an auxiliar value.

```
const[isUpdating, setIsUpdating] = useState(false);
```

When user is updating info, I set the value for isUpdating to true. So when the component is rendered I need to add some check to force label shrink

```
<TextField                                            
    {...register("name")}
    label='Name' 
    InputLabelProps={{shrink: isUpdating }} />
```

It worked for me, Hope it helps.